# ShellScript Issue Linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell

> Task 1:
>
> If the Time is AM, print "It is Morning". If it is PM, print "It is not morning".
>
> Task 2:
>
> Given 2 arguments passed to the script.
>
> Validate that 2 arguments have been submitted. If three arguments have not been provided, print "Must Supply 2 Arguments" and exit the script
>
> - Argument 1: Should be a directory (needs validated). If this does not exist, print "Directory: directory, does not exist" and exit the script
> - Argument 2: Should be a file (needs validated). If this does not exist, print "File: filename, does not exist" and exit the script.
>
> If all arguments are valid, print "Given valid: filename and directory"

This is what I have so far

```
echo "James DuBois: 555555 - Task 1"
TIME=$(date "+%H")
if [ $TIME -lt 12 ]; then
    echo "morning"
else
    echo "not morning"
fi

echo "Task 2"

[ -d "$1" ] || exit
[ -d "$2" ] || exit
[ $# == 2 ] || exit

echo "arg1: $1"
echo "arg2: $2"
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I am trying to wrap my head around task 2. I have no clue how arguments work with linux. Just doing some googling at the moment to come up with some code.

Comment: Why would `hours >= 12` be **morning**? Perhaps `-lt 12` would make more sense? For **task 2**, same type of test, but you need the conditional expression to test for a file, perhaps `-f`? Do this for me **exactly** `man bash`, then `/CONDITIONAL\ EXPRESSIONS` Let me know if that doesn't solve it for you.

Comment: I think im kinda on the right track? To be honest im not too sure whats going on.

Comment: StackOverflow is a great resource when you've isolated a question and need to find an answer for it. It doesn't sound like you've isolated a question here; there's a wide gap between a program specification and a specific problem you're having when implementing that specification. Two *separate* program specifications are even less of an isolated question.

Comment: My question would to be how to implement task 2 the best way possible.

Comment: `[ -d "$2" ]` needs to be `[ -f "$2" ]` if it's a not a directory but a file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

James, BASH is a wonderful, flexible shell. It has its warts, but if you need to do anything having to do with Linux system administration, etc.., you can do it in bash. Your tasks are to familiarize you with using **conditional expressions** (tests). There are tests for just about anything you need. That's why I pointed you to the **CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS** part of `man bash`.

Your second task requires the input of a `filename` so you can test it. I presume it is intended to be passed as an argument to your script (called **positional parameters**). Here is one way to approach the test. **Note:** I have interchanged output routines `echo` and `printf` intentionally for your benefit (`printf` being a bit more robust). Take a look at the following and let me know what questions you have:

```
#!/bin/bash
# My first script
#
#  echo & printf are used at random below -- intentionally
#

[ -z $1 ] && {  # validate at least 1 argument given on command line
    printf "error: insufficient input. usage:  %s filename\n" "${0##*/}"
    exit 1
}

printf "\nJames DuBois: 5555555\n\n  Task 1\n\n"
TIME=$(date "+%H")

## test for time of date: morning/not morning
if [ $TIME -lt 12 ]; then
    printf " morning - time for coffee\n"
else
    echo " not morning - time for scotch"
fi

echo -e "\n  Task 2\n"

printf "Testing whether '%s' is a valid file.\n\n" "$1"

## test for file using compound commands
[ -f "$1" ] && echo -e " file found: '$1'\n" || printf " file not found: '%s'\n\n" "$1"

echo -e "Second test whether '$1' is a valid file.\n"

## test for file using if; then; else; fi
if [ -f "$1" ]; then
    printf " file found: '%s'\n\n" "$1"
else
    echo -e " file not found: '$1'\n"
fi

exit 0
```

**Use/Output**

```
$ bash ~/scr/tmp/stack/morningfile.sh
error: insufficient input. usage:  morningfile.sh filename

$ bash ~/scr/tmp/stack/morningfile.sh mtrx_simple_dyn.c

James DuBois: 5555555

  Task 1

 not morning - time for scotch

  Task 2

Testing whether 'mtrx_simple_dyn.c' is a valid file.

 file found: 'mtrx_simple_dyn.c'

Second test whether 'mtrx_simple_dyn.c' is a valid file.

 file found: 'mtrx_simple_dyn.c'

$ bash ~/scr/tmp/stack/morningfile.sh dog.c

James DuBois: 5555555

  Task 1

 not morning - time for scotch

  Task 2

Testing whether 'dog.c' is a valid file.

 file not found: 'dog.c'

Second test whether 'dog.c' is a valid file.

 file not found: 'dog.c'
```

Answer (score 0):

This will have some additional advantages while doing the same thing in **task 2**:

```
echo "Task 2"

[[ -d $1 && ! -L $1 && -f $2 && ! -L $2 ]] || exit
printf "%s\n" "arg1: $1" "arg2: $2"
```

It checks for symbolic links with the `-L` option.

`[[ ]]` has some advantages over `[ ]` like dealing with white spaces without the need for quoting variables.

If you want to print messages while checking for directory and file:

```
[[ ! -d $1 || -L $1 ]] && echo "Directory doesn't exist" && exit
[[ ! -f $2 || -L $2 ]] && echo "File doesn't exist" && exit
printf "%s\n" "arg1: $1" "arg2: $2"
```